# InHouse App - "MyAppName" is no longer available

Tags: ios, ipad, in-house-distribution

I'm creating an in-house app using an enterprise certificate.
The IPA is correctly installed in an iPad, and when running it, first it asks about:

```
Untrusted App Developer
Do you trust the developer "XXX" to run apps on your iPad?
Trust  -  Don't trust
```

But after trusting the developer I receive next message:

```
"MyAppName" Is No Longer Available
```

Last week I could perfectly run any in-house app created with same certificate. In other devices the in-house apps work fine, so I guess it's a problem with my iPad.